# how would the different programs execute/call each other and exchange information

Tags: servlets

Java Servlet can be used as part of a hybrid solution (i.e. website using many different programming languages.) But how a hybrid solution would work, i.e. how would the different programs execute/call each other and exchange information? 
Please don't use code to explain. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can 'exchange data.' It all depends on the your application.

You could use XML to define your data, as many programming languages support digesting/serializing XML. You could also use JSON (more for javascript), or direct socket connection as mentioned above.

I have seen C# Client applications that write java byte code to send to server implemented in java. The answer depends on the specific details of your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in many ways.

Java can call other languages that run in the JVM directly, or languages outside the JVM by using JNI.

Portions of such a system could also be running as separate processes with communication by methods such as web-services or sockets.